# UILabel height animation with autolayout

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout

I have an UILabel on my view and UIButton. When button touched UILabel should change height animated, depends on label content . I was trying this:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        self.textLabel= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.textLabel.numberOfLines=0;
        self.textLabel.font= [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
        self.textLabel.backgroundColor= [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        self.textLabel.text= @"short text";
        [self.view addSubview:self.textLabel];
        [self.textLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[_textLabel]-10-|"
        options:0
        metrics:nil
        views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_textLabel)]];


        self.button= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
        [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.button setTitle:@"Tap" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.button.backgroundColor= [UIColor greenColor];
        [self.button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [self.view addSubview:self.button];

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[_button]-10-|"
                                   options:0
                                   metrics:nil
                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_button)]];

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-50-[_textLabel(>=0)]-10-[_button(==20)]"
                                   options:0
                                   metrics:nil
                                    views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_textLabel,_button)]];

}

- (void)buttonTouched:(id)buttonTouched {
        self.shortText =!self.shortText;
        self.textLabel.text= self.shortText ?@"short text":@"long long long text\nlong long long text\nlong long long text\n";
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                         animations:^{
                             [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: Does the result of the text change appear correctly at the moment when the button is touched, and you are just trying to animate it?  Or is the resulting frame of the button wrong as well?

Comment: @obuseme resulting frame is correct, but it changes without animation

Comment: Ok, see my answer below.  You are just missing one line

Comment: @obuseme I just checked your solution. UILabel frame changes without animation. Looks like frame changes immediately after self.textLabel.text change.

Answer (score 5):

Right before the animation block, you need to call `[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints]` in order to trigger tell the view that the constraints need to be updated when you call `layoutIfNeeded`

So the new method:

```
- (void)buttonTouched:(id)buttonTouched {
    self.shortText =!self.shortText;
    self.textLabel.text= self.shortText ?@"short text":@"long long long text\nlong long long text\nlong long long text\n";
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this example working no problem.

```html
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    __weak UIView *_bgView;
    __weak UILabel *_label;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    bgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:bgView];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[bgView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(bgView)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[bgView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(bgView)]];
    _bgView = bgView;
    
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    label.backgroundColor = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
    label.text = @"ahoj";
    label.numberOfLines = 99;
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [bgView addSubview:label];
    [bgView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-8-[label]-8-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label)]];
    [bgView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-8-[label]-8-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label)]];
    _label = label;
    
    [self performSelector:@selector(animate) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}

- (void)animate
{
    _label.text = @"ahoj, ahoj\ntotalka ahoj";
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        [_bgView.superview layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        ;
    }];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I've checked your code. UILabel frame changes without animation.

Answer (score 0):

Define the height constraint in your storyboard, add it as an IBOutlet, and then change its value inside your animation block.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use

```
[self.textLabel sizeToFit];
```

it works.